# Titration of multi-basic acid

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, ph

> How would a solution made of $\pu{20 mL}$ of $\ce{NaOH}$, $\pu{10 mL}$ of $\ce{HCl}$, $\pu{10 mL}$ $\ce{NaH2PO4}$ and $\pu{5 mL}$ of $\ce{Na3PO4}$, all of them in a concentration of $\pu{10 mmol/L}$, behave? I already tried every way i can think of, but none give the solution of the $\mathrm{pH}$ of this system.

Ways I tried:

1. After reacting the $\ce{HCl}$ with $\ce{NaOH}$, I use the $\ce{NaOH}$ that i still got to react with $\ce{NaH2PO4}$, and to calculate the $[\ce{H+}]$ I used $[\ce{Na2HPO4}]$ + $\ce{[Na3PO4]}$, but i didnt got any answers.
2. I used this equation $\ce{NaH2PO4 + 2NaOH -> Na3PO4 + 2H2O}$ to find the concentration and then applied to the amphoteric equation, using $K_{a_2}$ and $K_{a_3}$.

Answer (score 4):

$
\begin{align}
(n_{\ce{NaOH}})_i= \pu{0.2 mmol}\\
(n_{\ce{HCl}})_i= \pu{0.1 mmol}\\
(n_{\ce{NaH2PO4}})_i= \pu{0.1 mmol}\\
(n_{\ce{Na3PO4}})_i= \pu{0.05 mmol}
\end{align} 
$

At first the $\ce{NaOH}$ will react with $\ce{HCl}$ as per the following reaction:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\ce{NaOH} & + & \ce{HCl} & \ce{->} & \ce{NaCl} & + & \ce{H2O} \\
\pu{0.2 mmol} & & \pu{0.1 mmol} & & \pu{0 mmol} & & \\
\pu{0.1 mmol} & & \pu{0 mmol} & & \pu{0.1 mmol} & & \\
\end{array}
\end{align}
$$
Now, the remaining $\ce{NaOH}$ will react with $\ce{NaH2PO4}$ as per following:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\ce{NaOH} & + & \ce{NaH2PO4} & \ce{->} & \ce{Na2HPO4} & + & \ce{H2O} \\
\pu{0.1 mmol} & & \pu{0.1 mmol} & & \pu{0 mmol} & & \\
\pu{0 mmol} & & \pu{0 mmol} & & \pu{0.1 mmol} & & \\
\end{array}
\end{align}
$$

Now the resulting solution is  a buffer of $\ce{HPO4^2-}$ and $\ce{PO4^3-}$. So the Henderson equation can be used.

$
[\ce{PO4^3-}]=\frac{0.05}{45} \pu{M}\\
[\ce{HPO4^2-}]=\frac{0.1}{45} \pu{M}\\
$

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathrm{pH} & = & \mathrm{pK_{a_3}} + \log(\frac{[\ce{PO4^3-}]}{[\ce{HPO4^2-}]}) \\
\mathrm{pH} & = & 12.35 + \log(\frac{0.05}{0.1})\\
\mathrm{pH} & = & 12.35 + \log(\frac{1}{2})\\
\mathrm{pH} & = & 12.04 \\
\end{array}
\end{align}
$$